# Can someone explain why these two things mean the same thing?

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Here are two functions that do the same thing. Can someone explain how?

```
 void calculateFace(){
   //READ THE DIP SWITCH
   int sw_one = digitalRead(LandingStartSW);
   int sw_two = digitalRead(LandingApproachSW);
   int sw_three = digitalRead(LandingTerminalSW);
 
   displayBitmap = (sw_three << 2) | (sw_two << 1) | sw_one;
 
 }
```

and

```
void calculateFace(){
 READ THE DIP SWITCH
 int  sw_one = digitalRead(LandingStartSW);
 int  sw_two = digitalRead(LandingApproachSW);
 int  sw_three = digitalRead(LandingTerminalSW);
 
 if(sw_one == 1 && sw_two == 0 && sw_three == 0) {
 displayBitmap = 1;
}
else if(sw_one == 0 && sw_two == 1 && sw_three == 0) {
 displayBitmap = 2;
}
 else if(sw_one == 1 && sw_two == 1 && sw_three == 0) {
 displayBitmap = 3;
}
else if(sw_one == 0 && sw_two == 0 && sw_three == 1) {
 displayBitmap = 4;
}
else if(sw_one == 1 && sw_two == 0 && sw_three == 1) {
 displayBitmap = 5;
}
else if(sw_one == 0 && sw_two == 1 && sw_three == 1) {
 displayBitmap = 6;
}
else if(sw_one == 1 && sw_two == 1 && sw_three == 1) {
 displayBitmap = 7;
}
else {
 displayBitmap = 0;
}
```

I tried understanding it myself. I understand that the first one is bitshifting the values, but I can't figure out how that's translating to if else statements.

Comment: Please use code blocks instead of quotation blocks when you enter your code here

Comment: The shfits aren't translating to if statements. They merely result in the same end value.

Comment: Compare `a+b` to `if(a==0 && b==0) return 0; if (a==1 && b==0) return 1; if (a==0 && b==1) return 1; if (a==1 && b==1) return 2;`. They don't translate to each other, but end up with the same results (for certain inputs)

Comment: Would you agree that three variables holding either `0` or `1` have 8 possible permutations?

Comment: Take a look at the pattern of 1s and 0s in the `if` statements. Look familiar? Look sorta... like a three bit integer?

Comment: Those two function are not equivalent if `digitalRead`could return a value other than 0 or 1. And if they are returning boolean value, it would be preferable that the return type would be a `bool`.

Comment: The second function is really bad because it is way too long. Anyone with very minimal competence can easily see that the second function would be very terrible if there would be even more bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider the variables `sw_one`, `sw_two`, and `sw_three` as "bits" of one 3-bit number consisting of them. The less significant bit is `sw_one`, the most significant bit is `sw_three`, and between them is `sw_two`.

This number can contain the following values in binary:

| sw_three | sw_two | sw_one | decimal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 6 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 7 |

The right hand expression in this statement:

```
displayBitmap = (sw_three << 2) | (sw_two << 1) | sw_one;
```

builds a single 3-bit number as shown above from these three "bit" values.

The `if` statements, like for example this:

```
else if(sw_one == 1 && sw_two == 0 && sw_three == 1) {
  displayBitmap = 5;
}
```

just tests each bit value of a built number and provides the corresponding decimal value.

Compare this `if` statement with the binary representation of the value 5 in the above table:

| sw_three | sw_two | sw_one | decimal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 5 |

Comment: Thank you, this really helped clear things up for me. I appreciate your kindness and assistance.